# Closing window from ViewModel in another Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have MVVM, where VM is in separate ClassLibrary project. I need to implement closing window.
All solutions that I see involve passing window directly. The problem is that Class Library doesn't know `System.Windows.Window` type so, even though I can pass the form as object I cannot call a `Close` method on it.

What should I do? Is there a solution, specific for Class Libraries?

Comment: Can you pass an event? Delegate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing Child Window from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294156/closing-child-window-from-viewmodel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should the ViewModel close the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form)

Comment: May be you can use `Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();` in PCL. Give it a try.

Comment: Also check this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d10de84c-bef1-46ed-8127-7ad19b8eec37/using-a-wpf-window-in-a-class-library-project?forum=wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to define an interface in the class library where the view models are defined:

```
public interface IWindow
{
    void Close();
}
```

Implement this interface in your window classes in the WPF application:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IWindow { ... }
```

You can pass an `IWindow` reference to the view model instead of passing a `System.Windows.Window` reference. Then the view model knows only about an interface that can be easily mocked out in an unit test.

You may also want to consider using a window service to open and close windows. Please refer to my answer to the following question for an example:

[MVVM show new window from VM when seperated projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352870/mvvm-show-new-window-from-vm-when-seperated-projects/47353136#47353136)

Comment: Referencing any U.I. element in the ViewModel is 100% against the principals of  MVVM.

Comment: @Peregrine: Yes but referencing a custom interface is certainly not.